# Counters and countered by

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the difference in meaning of the two sentences below?

Cavalry counters Infantry. 
Infantry is countered by Cavalry.

Can I read it like:
Cavalry attacks Infantry. 
Infantry is attacked by Cavalry. 
?

Comment: If cavalry counters infantry, then it is infantry that is doing the attacking, not cavalry.  Here *counters* is describing a counter attack defense.  Infantry is countered by cavalry also implies that infantry is doing the attacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I read it like: Cavalry attacks Infantry. Infantry is attacked by
>   Cavalry. ?

No, *counters* doesn't mean attack.

Counters is being used as a transitive verb here:

See 1.b at [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counter)

> b : offset, nullify... *tried to counter the trend toward
>   depersonalization*

The cavalry are nullifying the impact of the infantry. If you visualise cavalry and infantry, the reason for the nullification will likely be obvious.

The second sentence, is just restating the first sentence in reverse order.

> Infantry is countered by Cavalry.

If A counters B, then by definition B is countered by A.

Comment: But it does imply calvary is engaging actions against Infantry, right? Something like... hey I see a bunch of infantry coming towards me, let's do something about it.

Comment: Well the sentences are statements, there's no first person here, or present continuous tense of 'I see... coming towards me' but a general statement that says if you have infantry, their impact would be nullified by cavalry. Although we usually think of infantry and cavalry on the battlefield, there is no mention of battle here. So the statement need not imply anything about engaging in conflict. For instance if there was a military display with infantry and cavalry parading, the meaning could be that the cavalry outshine the infantry. But yes the implication most would think of here... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 is one of battle, and if the cavalry are countering the infantry on the battlefield, then they would be engaging in actions that overpower the infantry in battle.